# Integral with substitution (Proof)

Tags: calculus, integration

Having a bit of difficulty showing the following equality holds:

$$\int_0^x f(t)(x-t)\ dt = \int_0^x\left(\int_0^tf(v)\ dv \right)\ dt.$$

Whenever $f$ is an integrable function on $[0,x]$. My thought process so far:

\begin{align}
\notag \int_0^xf(t)(x-t)\ dt &= \int_0^xf(t)\left(\int_t^x\ du \right)\ dt\\
\notag &= \int_0^x\left(\int_t^xf(t)\ du \right)\ dt.
\end{align}

This is the most genuine progress I have made. This problem comes from Larson's 8th edition Calculus text after the section on substitution, so I've been looking for a way to use substitution from here, but haven't had any luck. Thanks

Edit: Assume I cannot use integration by parts, only basic substitution methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $\displaystyle F(x)=\int \limits_0^x f(t)(x-t)\mathrm dt - \int \limits_0^x\left(\int \limits_0^tf(v)\mathrm dv \right)\mathrm dt$, for all $x$ on an **interval** where $f$ is continuous.

Clearly $\displaystyle F(x)=x\int \limits_0^x f(t)\mathrm dt-\int \limits_0^x tf(t)\mathrm dt - \int \limits_0^x\left(\int \limits_0^tf(v)\mathrm dv \right)\mathrm dt$.

Differentiating $F$ yields $$F'(x)=\int \limits_0^xf(t)\mathrm dt+xf(x)-xf(x)-\int \limits _0^xf(v)\mathrm dv=0.$$

Therefore $F$ is constant in the aforementioned interval. Since $F(0)=0$, the result follows.

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken but to differentiate an integral at a point don't you need that the function is continuous at the same point?

Comment: @user71352 Yes, thanks for spotting the mistake.

Comment: Your welcome. No worries.

Comment: @chs21259 See my comment on the other answer. Without further assumptions my answer doesn't work as I require $f$ to be continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Use integration by parts

$\int_{0}^{x}f(t)(x-t)dt=(\int_{0}^{t}f(v)dv)(x-t)|_{0}^{x}+\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{t}f(v)dvdt=\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{t}f(v)dvdt$.

Comment: Notice that this only works when $f$ is integrable.  I think OP meant to add this.

Comment: Yes, $f$ must be integrable, but this problem is in the section before integration by parts, so I've been trying not to use it. I'll edit the post. This helps though!

Comment: You can also change the order of integration.

Comment: That's a great suggestion Gaffney. chs21259 are you familiar with Fubini's Theorem?

Comment: Not currently, I can look it up though! I've taken classes up to and including basic undergrad analysis, would it be over my head?

Comment: I believe Fubini's Theorem is first covered in Second Year Calculus. It won't be over your head. It just deals with changing the order of integration.

Comment: @chs21259 I think Fubini's Theorem usually requires continuity. With 'usually' I mean in calculus books, so I think Fubini's theorem works if, and only if, my answer works (which it doesn't, at the moment). Are you sure continuity isn't one of the hypothesis?

Comment: @Git Gud It didn't specify continuity. The problem just says "Prove that:" and then it gives the equality. I thought it was odd as well, and there is nothing before that question saying "For problems 6-9 assume...". Also, I am familiar with Fubini's Theorem, I just never realized it was called that. I'll give it a shot! (Assuming continuity)